# Error Formula parse error in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Can anyone check if i have made any mistake in this formulae I am trying to apply on the data validation custom formulae?

=AND(((vlookup($C3,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qNiwM2cvp_E7H64w4tKk8GrXbG794vF3CdRQEosSv2g/edit#gid=1905387885","'Project Profile Summary'!c2:ah"),32,0))>=0.35),(NOT($D3="Completed")),((NOT((vlookup($C3,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qNiwM2cvp_E7H64w4tKk8GrXbG794vF3CdRQEosSv2g/edit#gid=1905387885","'Project Profile Summary'!c2:ah"),6,0))=”Investment”)))

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be your curly quotes `=”Investment”`. They'll need to be `"`.